# How to share data between components using different React.render() function

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Inside of my react application i am calling `React.render()` multiple times to render different components ( business need ). We know that to share data between a component tree we can use `Context` but how to share data in this case of different `React.render()`s in such a way that components are reactive to state/prop changes as well. thanks

Comment: Can you show us an code example of what you want?